# Read/Write Excel Files Directly To/From Memory

Tags: excel, memory

Several people have asked, in a roundabout way, but I have yet to see a workable solution.  Is there any way to open an excel file directly from memory (like a byte[]) ?  Likewise is there a way to write a file directly to memory?  I am looking for solutions that will not involve the hard disk or juggling temporary files.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: How did the excel file end up in memory?  I've noticed that people are often afraid of saving things to disk when they shouldn't be.  Flushing the byte array to disk is going to have a very minor cost compared to the processing that excel will do when you open it.
Oh, and I'm 99% sure that the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: You get a spreadsheet file in memory of you are doing things like pulling it from sharepoint within a webservice, or if you are saving them as a byte blob in a database.  These are just a few examples.  Using a filesystem is just an (seemingly) unnecessary middle step that uses a slower bus and causes potential resource/race condition headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not support saving to memory, at least not that I have been able to find - and I have looked because I could use it.

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can save to and load from a byte array. Here is a simple example:

```
using System;
using SpreadsheetGear;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a simple Hello World workbook.
            IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook();
            IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Hello World";
            // Save to memory.
            byte[] data = workbook.SaveToMemory(FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
            // Load from memory and output the contents of A1.
            workbook = Factory.GetWorkbookSet().Workbooks.OpenFromMemory(data);
            worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            Console.WriteLine("A1={0}", worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see live SpreadsheetGear samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC